# How to position a table centered with a static size?

Tags: css, css-tables

This doesn't work.

```
table {                                                                         
  border-collapse: collapse;                                                    
  margin : 1.62rem auto;                                                        
  font-family : "DejaVu Sans Mono";                                             
  display : block;                                                              
  overflow : auto;                                                              
}
```

Yes, it's possible to center table width:

```
table {
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

But how make it be simultaneously at the center and don't increase the width on smartphones?

---

solution:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: you can add a max-width property. Maybe do something like max-width: 50vw; or however large you want it to be? I don't know if it'd work in this particular case, but that's the first thing I'd try

Comment: Just use the CSS property max-width. For example: .table { max-width: 80%; }

Comment: Except since his problem is on mobiles, I'd use vw rather than percentage.  Using vh and vw it better at handling weird screen sizes and resolutions than pixels and percentages! They are also percentages, but base on the viewport height and width, which makes your pages look better on a multitude of different screens sizes and shapes!

Comment: I know about max-width and viewport units.  The problem is in fact that it's not possible to center and make it scrollable in proper way at one time. If to add max-width, it, doesnt help - on smartphone scrollbar appears, but it's not at the center on desktop.